# How to write parser in non linear equation?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function plot(equation) {
    var graph;
    var xPadding = 30;
    var yPadding = 30;

    var data = {
        values : [{
                X : "1",
                Y : 15
            }, {
                X : "2",
                Y : 35
            }, {
                X : "3",
                Y : 60
            }, {
                X : "4",
                Y : 14
            }, {
                X : "5",
                Y : 20
            }, {
                X : "6",
                Y : -30
            },
        ]
    };

    // Returns the max Y value in our data list
    function getMaxY() {
        var max = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < data.values.length; i++) {
            if (data.values[i].Y > max) {
                max = data.values[i].Y;
            }
        }

        max += 10 - max % 10;
        return max;
    }
    var scaleA = 1.4;
    // Return the x pixel for a graph point
    function getXPixel(val) {
        return ((graph.width() / scaleA  - xPadding) / data.values.length) * val + (xPadding * 1.5);
    }

    // Return the y pixel for a graph point
    function getYPixel(val) {
        return graph.height() / scaleA  - (((graph.height() / scaleA  - yPadding) / getMaxY()) * val) - yPadding;
    }

    graph = $('#graph');
    var c = graph[0].getContext('2d');
    c.clearRect(0,0,graph[0].width,graph[0].height);
    c.lineWidth = 2;
    c.strokeStyle = '#333';
    c.font = 'italic 8pt sans-serif'; 
    c.textAlign = "center";

    // Draw the axises
    c.beginPath();
    c.moveTo(xPadding, 0);
    c.lineTo(xPadding, graph.height() / scaleA  - yPadding);
    c.lineTo(graph.width(), graph.height() / scaleA  - yPadding);
    c.stroke();

    // Draw the X value texts
    for (var i = 0; i < data.values.length; i++) {
        c.fillText(data.values[i].X, getXPixel(i), graph.height() / scaleA  - yPadding + 20);
    }

    // Draw the Y value texts
    c.textAlign = "right"
        c.textBaseline = "middle";

    for (var i = 0; i < getMaxY(); i += 10) {
        c.fillText(i, xPadding - 10, getYPixel(i));
    }

    c.strokeStyle = '#f00';

    // Draw the line graph
    c.beginPath();
    c.moveTo(getXPixel(0), getYPixel(equation(0)));
    for (var i = 1; i < data.values.length; i++) {
        c.lineTo(getXPixel(i), getYPixel(equation(i)));
    }
    c.stroke();

    // Draw the dots
    c.fillStyle = '#333';

    for (var i = 0; i < data.values.length; i++) {
        c.beginPath();
        c.arc(getXPixel(i), getYPixel(equation(i)), 4, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
        c.fill();
    }
}
var codeText = "";
function parseEquation(input){
    // Important that white spaces are removed first
    input = input.replace(/\s+/g,""); // remove whitespaces
    input = input.replace(/([\-\+])([xy])/g,"$11$2"); // convert -x -y or +x +y to -1x -1y or +1x +1y
                                                      // just to make the logic below a little simpler
    var newTerm = () => {term = { val : null, scalar : 1, left : left, };} // create a new term
    var pushTerm = () => {terms.push(term); term = null;} // push term and null current
    // regExp [xy=] gets "x","y", or "="" or [\-\+]??[0-9\.]+  gets +- number with decimal
    var reg =/[xy=]|[\-\+]??[0-9\.eE]+/g;   // regExp to split the input string into parts
    var parts = input.match(reg);           // get all the parts of the equation
    var terms = [];     // an array of all terms parsed
    var term = null;    // Numbers as constants and variables with scalars are terms
    var left = true;    // which side of equation a term is
    parts.forEach(p=>{ 
         if (p === "x" || p === "y") {
            if (term !== null && term.val !== null) {  // is the variable defined
                 pushTerm(); // yes so push to the stack and null 
            }
            if (term === null) { newTerm(); }  // do we need a new term?
            term.val = p;
        } else if( p === "="){                // is it the equals sign
            if (!left) { throw new SyntaxError("Unxpected `=` in equation."); }
            if (term === null) { throw new SyntaxError("No left hand side of equation."); }// make sure that there is a left side
            terms.push(term);   // push the last left side term onto the stack
            term = null;
            left = false;       // everything on the right from here on in
        } else {                // all that is left are numbers (we hope)
            if (isNaN(p)){ throw new SyntaxError("Unknown value '"+p+"' in equation");  }//check that there is a number
            if (term !== null && (p[0] === "+" || p[0] === "-")){ // check if number is a new term
                 pushTerm();    // yes so push to the stack and null 
            }
            if(term === null){ newTerm(); } // do we need a new term?
            term.scalar *= Number(p);       // set the scalar to the new value
        }
    });
    
    if(term !== null){// there may or may not be a term left to push to the stack
        pushTerm();
    }
    // now simplify the equation getting the scalar for left and right sides . x on left y on right
    var scalarX = 0;
    var scalarY = 0
    var valC = 0; // any constants 
    terms.forEach(t => {
        t.scalar *= !t.left ? -1 : 1; // everything on right is negative
        if (t.val === "y") {
            scalarY += -t.scalar; // reverse sign
        } else if (t.val === "x") {
            scalarX += t.scalar; 
        } else {
            valC += t.scalar;
        }
    })
    // now build the code string for the equation to solve for x and return y
    var code = "return (" + scalarX + " * x  + (" + valC + ")) / "+scalarY +";\n";
    codeText = code;
    var equation = new Function("x",code); // create the function
    
    return equation;
}


function parseAndPlot(){
  var input = eqInput.value;
  try{
     var equation = parseEquation(input);
     plot(equation);
     error.textContent ="Plot of "+input+ " as 'function(x){ "+codeText+"}'";      
  }catch(e){
     error.textContent = "Error parsing equation. " + e.message;      
  }
  
} 


var button = document.getElementById("plot");
var eqInput = document.getElementById("equation-text");
var error = document.getElementById("status");
button.addEventListener("click",parseAndPlot);
parseAndPlot();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="graph" width="200" height="150"></canvas> <br>
Enter a linear equation : <input id="equation-text" value="x2 + 5y = 250" type="text"></input><input id="plot" value="plot" type=button></input><div id="status"></div>
```

I have some code in parser in linear equation but i want to parser in non linear equation how to write the parser in non linear equation in maths for example x3+x4-20x2=0 and x^100+x^200+x^1000=0 how to find the power parser values so please help me.

Comment: please any one can help to answer for this question help me.

Comment: You have 4 questions on the subject of parsing the steps needed to solve equations -- and they seem to be asking roughly the same question. You might consider consolidating your questions into one question that answerers can focus on. Be sure to tag that one question with the library that you're using (MathJS, is it?) so that gurus in that tag will see your question. Beyond that, **be patient!** Stackoverflow is manned largely by people with day jobs so it might take time for the right answerer to have free time to post your answer. Cheers! :-)